# Avoiding nested conditionals and comparing strings

Tags: coffeescript

I have a web page with a set of icons that are grey by default:

[image]

If a user clicks one, it toggles green (`.toggleClass('green')`):

[image]

If a user clicks a green one, it toggles back to grey (`.removeClass('green')`).

Only one icon can be green at any given time, so if you have a green icon and you click a grey icon, the icon that was originally green will change to grey while the one you clicked would change to green.

---

Each of these icons corresponds to a section on the page.

- If all the icons are grey, all the sections on the page are visible.
- If one icon is green, only that icon's section is visible, the sections represented by the grey icons are hidden.

---

Here is the code that controls that behavior:

```
$(document).on 'click', '.toggler', ->
  icons = [$('#toggle-videos'),$('#toggle-images'),$('#toggle-words')]
  sections = [$('#videos'),$('#images'),$('#words')]
  if $(this).hasClass('green')
    $(this).toggleClass('green')
    i = 0
    while i < sections.length
      sections[i].show()
      i++
  else
    $(this).addClass('green')
    i = 0
    while i < icons.length
      if icons[i][0] != $(this)[0]
        icons[i].removeClass('green')
        sections[i].hide()
      else      
        j = 0
        while j < sections.length
          if $(this).attr('id').indexOf(sections[j].attr('id')) != -1
            sections[j].show()
          j++
      i++
```

I feel it is very hard to understand what this code does simply by reading it.  I feel I am missing a simpler way to accomplish the following:

- Associate an icon with a specific section on the page
- Keep the green state of an icon associated with the visibility of a specific section on the page

My primary concerns with the code:

- I have several nested if statements with nested while statements
- I am checking the relationship between a section and an icon by checking if the `icon.id` has part of the string (`this` is the icon element and `j` is a counter):
  `if $(this).attr('id').indexOf(sections[j].attr('id')) != -1`

**Is this acceptable for javascript or is there a better way?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery generally operates on *collections* of elements, so you rarely need to old-fashioned loops and incrementing indexes. In addition, CoffeeScript has many syntactic niceties for dealing with collections, which means that you hardly ever have to do old-fashioned looping.

I'd suggest keeping the link-to-section relationship in the HTML, like so:

```
<a class="toggle" href="#videos">...</a>
<a class="toggle" href="#words">...</a>
<a class="toggle" href="#images">...</a>
```

(using `href` has the added benefit that it'll still work, even with no JavaScript support)

Then, use that in your code to hide/show what's needed, e.g.

```
$ ->
  toggles  = $ ".toggle"
  sections = $ ".section" # or whatever selector works

  toggles.on "click", (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()

    target  = $ this
    section = $ target.attr("href") # get the associated section

    if target.hasClass("selected")
      target.removeClass("selected")
      sections.show() # show all sections
    else
      toggles.removeClass("selected") # remove selection from other links
      target.addClass("selected")     # select the clicked link
      sections.not(section).hide()    # hide other sections
      section.show()                  # show only the relevant section
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h8MvL/1/)

I've changed the selection class to `selected` rather than `green`, because "green" isn't a very descriptive name - or, in a sense, it's *much too* descriptive. Either way, the name's tied to the *look* rather than the *purpose/function* of the class.

Comment: Good point about the 'green' to 'selected' - I should have made that change before I even posted this here.  Someone else mentioned using data attributes, it seems you use the actual href attribute to fulfill a similar role.  I like this because it would give feedback on mouse-hover about what is going to happen.

Comment: @Ecnalyr Using data attributes is a perfectly valid solution too. I only use the `href` attribute here, because what we need to store - an element selector - has exactly the same syntax as a regular anchor link. Otherwise, I'd use a data attribute too. But, as mentioned, the links will make the page scroll to the correct section even if you remove all the javascript/coffeescript. I.e. it degrades gracefully

Comment: Also nice trick with sections.not(section). Probably doesn't make much sense in this case. But is more correct if show/hide will be replaced with fadeIn/Out e.g.

Comment: @StepanStepanov That depends how you the look & feel you want for the page; the original code just uses show/hide. But yes, you can just replace it with fadeIn/Out, if you want.

Answer (score 2):

I would propose to use data attributes. E.g. icons have data-section-id attribute.

```
if $(this).hasClass('green') // all should become greynow
{
    $('div.section').show(); // show all sections
    $(this).removeClass('green');
}
else // we turn one sectio on
{
    $('div.section').hide(); // show all sections
    $('#'+ $(this).data('sectionId')).show(); // show a corresponding section
    $('li.icon').removeClass('green'); // turn all icons off
    $(this).addClass('green'); // turn current one on
}
```

But of course, that requires some changes in HTML structure.

Comment: I have been using data attributes elsewhere in the same app to come up with a similar solution - glad to see it came up here.  Not a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

If you like fun jQuery chains, the following should work for you.

```
$(document).on 'click', '.toggler', ->
    targetSection = $(this)
        .parent()
        .find('green')
            .removeClass('green')
            .end()
        .end()
        .addClass('green')
        .data( 'target' )
    $('.section').not(targetSection).hide()
    $(targetSection).show()
```

One thing is that you would have to modify your icons to have `data-` attributes like so:

```
<a id="video-toggle" data-target='#videos'>...</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually don't review CoffeeScript, because I find it too hard too read. Your code is not too hard to read, so I will give it a shot.

I think in essence, you are trying too hard to show all but the one section, I would simply had all sections, and then show the one section you need. I would also cache `$(this)` for speed reasons and use more `[].forEach` for readability. Finally, `this.id` is more readable and faster than `$(this).attr('id')`

This untested counter proposal should illustrate what I mean:

```
$(document).on 'click', '.toggler', ->
  //Look up by `id`
  icons = ['toggle-videos','toggle-images','toggle-words']
  //Show via '#` + id
  sections = ['#videos','#images','#words']
  $this = $(this);
  if $this.hasClass('green')
    $this.removeClass('green')
    sections.forEach( (section) => section.show() )
  else
    $this.addClass('green')
    sections.forEach( (section) => section.hide() )
    sections[ icons.indexOf( this.id ) ].show();
```

Personally, and that is a bit more hackish, I would abuse the fact that the section id is postfixed to the toggle id and do this:

```
$(document).on 'click', '.toggler', ->
  $this = $(this);
  if $this.hasClass('green')
    $this.removeClass('green')
    sections.forEach( (section) => section.show() )
  else
    $this.addClass('green')
    sections.forEach( (section) => section.hide() )
    sections[ this.id.split("-")[1] ].show();
```

I might be tempted to put a `toggleClass` in there as well, but somehow the `if` and then the `removeClass` or `addClass` make this code easier to parse for me.

Comment: I did not know I could cache $(this) (I only 'do javascript' when I HAVE to).  You made some good points about performance, hadn't even considered it up to this point.

Comment: It's interesting you find CoffeeScript harder to read; I have the exact opposite experience. These days I only write plain JS for CodeReview answers :)

Comment: I think I'm getting old and (c)rusty ;]

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you shouldn't use "green" as a class name.  The name should be something generic, like "selected" or "current".  Your CSS will cause the current selection to be rendered as a green icon, but you shouldn't hard-code that assumption into the name of the CSS class itself.

What you have described is essentially a radio button (with the additional feature that [clicking on the currently selected item will deselect everything](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8318129/1157100)).  Therefore, if you start with radio buttons, [styled with images using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3896259/1157100), most of your work will be done already!

Comment: I would like the radio button idea to work - and it would ordinarily.  But I've failed to style with iconfonts in the past (probably my fault, not the fault of css itself), so I always stray away from this idea.  I may have to revisit it.